# Publishing fails with SI4T and aws-cloud-search AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: publishing, web8.5, si4t, publishingfailed

We have migrated SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5 and while configuring AWS cloud search by taking jars from following git hub repository https://github.com/SI4T/aws-cloud-search

After configuring AWS cloud search as per documentation when we published, It's failing at Deployment Commit phase. 
When looked through logs found below stack trace with error

> AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling - NoSuchMethodError

```
2018-12-08 06:29:54,016 ERROR TridionCommitStep - Commit failed for execution id:tcm:0-2414563-66560
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions. ExecutionId:tcm:0-2414563-66560
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:78)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionCommitStep.process(TridionCommitStep.java:28)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-2414563-66560 because of com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling(Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:70)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:226)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:76)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling(Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.uploadDocuments(AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.java:299)
    at org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexDispatcher.addDocuments(CloudSearchIndexDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer.dispatchAddContentToCloudSearch(CloudSearchIndexer.java:298)
    at org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer.commitAddContentToCloudSearch(CloudSearchIndexer.java:221)
    at org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer.commit(CloudSearchIndexer.java:140)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor.triggerIndexing(SearchIndexProcessor.java:274)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:189)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:65)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

posting cd storage config and search DAO bundle configued

```
<Storages>
            <StorageBindings>
                <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml"/>
            </StorageBindings>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="sqlServer" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                 <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="DEV02\SQL01"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Live"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                </DataSource>
                <Indexer 
            Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" 
            DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt" 
            access_key_id="AKIAIKEW" 
            authentication="explicit" 
            documentEndpoint="doc-dev-le-5yist4ubp3pr2gwevm22uq.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com"
            indexBatchSize="20" 
            secret_access_key="QT54AX8PC5TZNOqM9/pS"/>      
            </Indexer>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="DEV02\SQL01"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Live"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ce_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\website\SearchIndex\Resources"/>           
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
```

Search DAO Bundle

```
<StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchPageDAO"/>
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="Binary" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchBinaryContentDAO"/>
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
    </StorageDAOBundle>
```

can you please help

Comment: Can you please edit your question and share your pom.xml file and list of dependencies jars file names which you have prepared and uploaded to deployer service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had similar issue,

The current version of **aws-cloud-search** source **pom.xml** used with following versions

```
<tridion.version>7.1.0</tridion.version>
<si4t.version>1.0</si4t.version>
<amazonaws.version>1.10.16</amazonaws.version>
```

**Note:**

SDL Tridion Sites 8.5 (formerly SDL Web) - deployer service used following jars for AWS SQS.

```
aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.6.jar
aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.9.6.jar
```

I believe your current **aws-cloud-search** build has AWS SDK **1.10.16**, which you have to reduce to use **1.9.6** because it's conflict with **1.10.16**.

Also noticed that current **aws-cloud-search** source **pom.xml** used artifactId **aws-java-sdk**, which is downloading all the AWS SDK services jar files which are not necessary, instead use artifactId **aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch** to download only cloudsearch jar only.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can try using this **pom.xml** and rebuild and try to test it again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.si4t</groupId>
    <artifactId>si4t-cloudsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tridion.version>8.5.0</tridion.version>
        <si4t.version>1.3</si4t.version>
        <amazonaws.version>1.9.6</amazonaws.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.4</httpclient.version>
        <gson.version>2.2.2</gson.version>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.6.4</slf4j-api.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/dist</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- TODO: update this when using proper MVN versioning -->
                    <finalName>si4t-cloudsearch-1.0</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Do note the exclusions. These should come with the Tridion Deployer-->
                    <!-- TODO: check whether we need all of the AWS jars. If not - exclude! -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeGroupIds>com.tridion,org.slf4j,org.apache,commons-io,commons-codec,commons-logging</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeGroupIds>com.tridion,org.slf4j,org.apache,commons-io,commons-codec,commons-logging</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeGroupIds>com.tridion,org.slf4j,org.apache,commons-io,commons-codec,commons-logging</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- TODO: upload si4t to Maven -->
            <groupId>org.si4t</groupId>
            <artifactId>si4t-se</artifactId>
            <version>${si4t.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${amazonaws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_model</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_core</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Web 8 new -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_common_util</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_common_config_legacy</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Updated:**

SDL.DXA.Search.Module.2.0\modules\Search\deployer\lib\si4t-cloudsearch - which is using the correct version of AWS (1.9.6), you could also use that there also I can see it has all AWS SDK services jars. it's not the problem, I would say it's not necessary to keep all the AWS SDK files other than cloudsearch.

I hope it helps and it will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you velmurgan, I will try your solution and update my findings. one more doubt, can’t we use AWS cloud jar files from DXA 2.0 search module instead of rebuilding the jars?

Comment: SDL.DXA.Search.Module.2.0\modules\Search\deployer\lib\si4t-cloudsearch - which is using the correct version of AWS (1.9.6), you could also use that there also I can see it has all AWS SDK services jars. it's not the problem, I would say it's not necessary to keep all the AWS SDK files other than cloudsearch.

Comment: Can you please add above comment as answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer